# Can I use "PROJECT_NAME" in a Doxygen Doxyfile?

Tags: doxygen, doxygen-wizard

I have to specify the location of a tool to Doxygen, something like this in a Doxyfile:

```
TOOL_PATH = ../${PROJECT_NAME}/Third-party/tool.jar
```

where `PROJECT_NAME` is a Doxygen variable.

The `${}` syntax is not accepted, I also tried with `$`, `@` and `%`, but none works.

If I specify the complete path, the tool is found and launched correctly.

Comment: Have you tried adding quotes `TOOL_PATH = "../${PROJECT_NAME}/Third-party/tool.jar"` ?

Comment: Yes, same error: path does not exist. It does not substitute the string...

Comment: In the Doxyfile you can use environment variables, but configuration variables cannot be used in other configuration variables.

Comment: @albert - Do you mean I cannot use a configuration variable (in this case the name of the project, known by Doxygen) to build a path? Is there another way around?

Comment: Indeed the way around is to define an environment variable and use this in your Doxyfile.